# Including SelectionColor in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the property called **SelectionColor** in the **TextBox** class, for a simple Syntax Highlighter - I can't use directly a RichTextBox - it causes too many problems, that's why I try to do this.

Is there any way to make that property available for a TextBox?
If it isn't possible, I'd try to write my own, but I need an idea on how to do it, basically how it works - is it based on drawing strings over the original text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, using a TextBox for anything but plain text is a bad idea. First of all, you will eventually get a new feature to implement which is not present in TextBox and you will have to handle it manually. After some time you will implement a custom RichTextBox or something similar.

Second, it is relatively hard to even solve the problem you mentioned. Technically, you can override painting function (which you *have* to do if you want new functionality for TextBox). You can then let TextBox paint itself and paint the colored text above the image. **But** don't do it. You will get two (maybe more) problems:

- Flicker of image. Once the original textbox has drawn itself, the image can be shown on screen (if you don't use double buffering).
- Text alignment. It is hard to place colored text exactly above black text, plus you can run into problems with text rendering: you will need to *clear* area you're drawing in.

Comment: I understand, it seems I'll have to go back to RichTextBox. Thanks for the fast answer :)